# Why doesn't the latest installed version of apache2 for ubuntu 20.04 match what the CVE website has for the package details on focal?

Tags: apt, apache2, security

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 VM that has all patches applied. This CVE below shows that the patch for apache 2.53 has been applied already for the release focal.

According to this CVE, https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2022-31813, shows focal  Released (2.4.41-4ubuntu3.12) package.

When I run `dpkg -l` the output shows `apache2 2.4.53-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`.

The package listed from the CVE website under release 'Focal' (2.4.41-4ubuntu3.12) does not match what is installed in my OS (2.4.53-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).

Can someone help me explain why they do not match up?

Comment: Why do you expect them to match ? 2.4.53-1 (which is what you have installed) is newer than 2.4.41-4 (the version the CVE was released in). There has just been other updates after the CVE was released.

Comment: Looks like you've used [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2). The [2.4.53-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2/+build/23241829) package is a 2022-03-14 built. I think it's time to update. The latest version from the repositories is 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.12.

Comment: I do not have that PPA installed. `apt policy` does not show that PPA. I do not expect them to match, should not have said that. I need to confirm that the latest package of apache2 I have installed addresses CVE-2022-31813.

Comment: The reason I suspect them to match is because https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/ shows that the latest version of apache2 for Focal Fossa is 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.12.

`$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)"`

I am coming from a RHEL background where you can see which CVEs are applied to specific packages which apt cannot do, unless I am missing something. So you have to manually search for it. What I am searching for does not match up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't match because you're not using the patched package distributed by the Ubuntu Security Team (2.4.41-4ubuntu3.12).

Instead, you are using a package from a PPA (2.4.53-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).

- See http://packages.ubuntu.com for the current packages in the Ubuntu repositories.

Looking at that PPA's release history at http://launchpad.net, seems like that package was published in March 2022, three months before the CVE was disclosed.

- In other words, your PPA-provided package *might* be vulnerable. Depends upon the specifics of that particular vulnerability.

This is one of the classic risks of using PPAs. You often get newer software, but you're not getting CVE tracking and patching from the Ubuntu Security Team. You're getting it from that PPA maintainer. Some maintainers are great, some are not.

Comment: Thank you for the information. `apt policy` does not show that PPA. Is there another way to list to PPAs?

Comment: @enduser123456 check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and all files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` for all repos on your system.  Anything at ppa.launchpad.net is a PPA.  There may be additional repos you're using as well when you're using the deb.sury.org repos too.

Comment: All of the urls in sources.list point to http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/.
I have one mariadb.list under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: It looks like the person who stood this system up did a local install using `dpkg -i apache2.zip`, im not sure the background on this or why it is like this. I discovered the [local] flag is on 1222 packages. How do I change the system to use Ubuntu's apache2 instead of whatever was installed on this system locally?

Comment: @ThomasWard How do I change the system to use the standard Ubuntu apache2 package instead of this local apache2?

Comment: The ZIP file and `dpkg` don't work together.  If `apache2` shows up in your package manager, youi can do `sudo apt remove apache2 apache2-{common,data,bin}` and then run `sudo apt clean` adn then do `sudo apt update && sudo apt install apache2`.  That *should* clean up the old versions and install the version in the repositories rather than a local copy.

Comment: Opinion: If you cannot get a clear explanation about why your system is so haywired, then reinstall the system with stock Ubuntu. Then you KNOW the system's condition and won't waste time on unpleasant surprises.